# Automatically reconfigure waf project, if configuration files change

Tags: waf

I have a `wscript` which reads some files during the configure step and based on this sets some variabales.
How do I get waf to automatically re-configure the project, if one of the *configuration* files change, when running `waf build` instead of `waf configure build`?

Consider the following scenario:

1. `waf configure`
2. `waf build`
3. The content in configuration file `a.config` is changed
4. the user just runs `waf build`, instead of `waf configure build`.

--> How must the `wscript` look like, that it checks before running `build` if the configuration files have changed, and if so, the project is reconfigured before running `build`?

Example:

There is a file `a.config` and the `wscript` looks like this:

```py
# wscript
def configure(conf):
    a = conf.path.find_node('a.config')
    conf.env.config = a.read()

def build(bld):
    # check the configuration files are up to date.
    # actual build
    pass
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`configure` is not really for that. You can use the same code but in `build`:

```py
def build(bld):

    a = bld.path.find_node('a.config')
    bld.env.config = a.read()

    bld(features = "myfeature", vars = ["config"], ...)
```

You can directly use configure with `autoconfig`:

```py
from waflib import Configure

def options(opt):
    Configure.autoconfig = True

def configure(conf):
    conf.env.config = "my_value"

def my_processing(task):
    print "Processing..."

def build(bld):
    bld(rule = my_processing, vars = ["config"])
```

Any change to `conf.env.config` will trigger rebuild.

If you need to have separate config files, you can use `load`:

```py
def configure(conf):
    pass

def my_processing(task):
    print "Processing..."

def build(bld):
    bld.load("my_config", tooldir="my_config_dir")
    bld(rule = my_processing, vars = ["config1", "config2"])
```

with a `my_config_dir/my_config.py` file like that:

```py
def build(bld):

    bld.env.config1 = "one"
    bld.env.config2 = "two"
    # ...
```

`bld.load()` will execute the `build` function in my_config.

Any change to `config1` or `config2` will trigger rebuild

Comment: Changing the content of a does not lead to a rebuild if I use e.g., the c or cprogram feature. Did it work for you?

Comment: @softwareissoftware: My mistake. `vars` must be a list. Works for me.

Comment: Ok, that interesting. It works for your example (`rule=...`). But this does not work if you use a feature. Do you have an idea what could be the problem?

Comment: Some features may change vars to fit their needs. For instance, the C task define `vars = ['CCDEPS']`. You can use CCDEPS directly or add a taskgen method to modify vars.

Comment: @softwareissoftware: In any case, I think you should use directly your configuration file as a dependency in your build. Configure is meant for tools and platform dependant configuration.